# spring transaction Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ no working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I test the spring transaction isolation use multi-threads. but I cannot get a good result. the test result show it is not working using spring transaction isolation.

I read a table row, if the canwrite column is true, I  update the canwrite column false and insert a row.

I use two threads, and the Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ, inserting two rows should not be happened.but I get it.

My code is as follows.

The Service code. there are two transaction.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public void T1() {
    Student one = crudRepository.findOne(1);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(one.getCanWrite()){
        one.setCanWrite(false);
        crudRepository.save(one);

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("T1");
        student.setAge(111);
        crudRepository.save(student);
    }
}
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public void T2() {
    Student one = crudRepository.findOne(1);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(one.getCanWrite()){
        one.setCanWrite(false);
        crudRepository.save(one);

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("T2");
        student.setAge(222);
        crudRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

the test code is :

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            service.T1();
        }
    },"T1").start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            service.T2();
        }
    },"T2").start();


    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

I print the transaction log, and the transaction is working. but why I get two rows inserted. the REPEATABLE_READ should prevent this.

**I use READ_UNCOMMITTED,READ_COMMITTED,REPEATABLE_READ, they all can not prevent this , and the SERIALIZABLE can, but get a dead lock exception.**

Comment: Looks like you need READ-UNCOMMITTED rather than REPEATABLE_READ

Comment: @StanislavL I use READ_UNCOMMITTED,READ_COMMITTED,REPEATABLE_READ all get   the two row inserted, I use SERIALIZABLE, the get a dead lock. and insert one row.

Comment: How do you create the services which are called from the test?

Comment: @StanislavL I use Autowired annotation.

Comment: Also try to `flush` after the `crudRepository.save(one);`

Comment: @StanislavL I add it , but no effect.